# Using BigIntegers as a condition in while loop in Java

Tags: java

I want to use a big integer value in my while loop condition but this is not working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class NiceProbelm2 {
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = input.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(number);
    BigInteger base = null;
    int power=0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          String token1 = st.nextToken();
          String token2 = st.nextToken();
          base = new BigInteger(token1);
          power = Integer.parseInt(token2);


        }

        BigInteger result = base.pow(power);
        //long fresult = (long)result;
        BigInteger div = new BigInteger("10");
        System.out.println(result);
        BigInteger sum=null;
     //NOt working while(result.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 10 )
                    {
        BigInteger digit = result.mod(div);
        result = result.divide(div);
        sum = sum.add(digit);

    }
     System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give us some sample inputs, outputs and expected results. It's hard to see what the problem is without knowing what the problem is. :)

Comment: Input: 1234567 8       output:5396563761318393964062660689603780554533710504641              output:sum of all the above numbers which is equal to 217

Comment: You need to tell us what *actually* gets output!

Comment: Let me make it clear again: input sample: 1234567 8 the program will calculate 1234567^8 which returns 5396563761318393964062660689603780554533710504641. I want to grab each digit in this long number and sum them up. This was possible for integers and doubles but not possible for big integer. The correct output should be 217.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem with the previous solutions were you had a null pointer that was being thrown because your accumulator was not initialized. The following code produces the result you are looking for:

```
        BigInteger result = base.pow(power);
        BigInteger div = new BigInteger("10");
        System.out.println(result);
//The following line is different, initialize the sum before using it.
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        while(!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(result)) {
            BigInteger digit = result.mod(div);
            result = result.divide(div);
            sum = sum.add(digit);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

I also wanted to point out that BigInteger has a method that provides both the quotient and remainder from a single division, which is more efficient than doing them both separately, and there is a "valueOf" method for BigInteger so you can use a numeric literal instead of a string:

```
    BigInteger result = base.pow(power);
    BigInteger div = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    System.out.println(result);

    //Initialize the sum to zero
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;        
    //While the result has a non-zero decimal digit
    while(!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(result)) {
        //this divides by ten (first element),
        //and calculates the remainder (second element)
        BigInteger[] lastDigit = result.divideAndRemainder(div);
        result = lastDigit[0];
        sum = sum.add(lastDigit[1]);

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: You are guru thanks a lot. I will look in to the other suggestions too.

Answer (score 7):

You should never compare the return value of [`compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) to anything other than 0. ([`BigInteger.compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigInteger%29) is a bit more specific, but the same rule still applies)

You can check if it's greater than 0, less than 0 or equal to 0. Only those 3 pieces of information are actually relevant. The actual value (if it returns 1 or 10 or 100) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this condition:

```
result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do `while (result != 0)` which you would write like
`while (result.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0)`

Also, you need to initialize `sum` to `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions but none of the above works. What I want to do is when i take the power of a number e.g. 1234567^8 gives me a very long number so I take the modulo of that number so I can get the digits one by one and add them up. Your suggestions above gave me the same results as before. The while loop involving the big integer argument is not executed.